# How to remove a blank line?

Tags: python

So basically, I'm making a password storage app, but when I write down the password the user enters in, python creates a blank line, which breaks my program. [Heres a picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzAMo.png)
So I'd need to get my program remove the second line somehow, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

The part where I need help:

```py
randompasswords = open("randomizedpsw.txt", "r")
choserandomnumber = random.randint(1, 39)
randomizedpassword = randompasswords.readlines()[choserandomnumber]
loginpsw = open('loginpsw.txt', 'w')
loginpsw.write(randomizedpassword)
loginpsw.close()
```

And so loginpsw.txt is the one with another empty line. That is what I need to remove somehow.
[Here's a picture of the random password possibilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pq49.png)

Comment: Please share your code to let us know how you are writing the password into file.

Comment: it's not about my code, it's about that an extra \n gets added to the end of it, and that's what I need to remove. So basically I need to remove a list's first item's last 2 letters. https://imgur.com/a/V0Qzqk6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It is definitely about your code. Either how you write to the file, or how you get the password. either way, without the code it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I included the part of my code that's probably the one where I need help, hopefully it'll help.

Comment: Thanks @Nqndi. Yes the problem is in your code while reading the file. Have a look at my answer below for detailed clarification. Let me know incase of any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.readlines()` method returns a list containing each line in the file as a list item.

If you specify a size as argument to the method, it will read the file untill the byte size specified is reached.

Now the file you are reading in your third line of code with some random int value will return that much byte separated by `\n`.

So, the value of

`randomizedpassword = randompasswords.readlines()[choserandomnumber]`

would look something like `["content of line 1\n", "content of line 2\n"]`

Hence the problem of `\n` arises when you are reading the file content ans storing it in a variable. The same gets written to the file later.

This is how you can get what you want , try this :

```
randompasswords = open("randomizedpsw.txt", "r")
choserandomnumber = random.randint(1, 39)
randomizedpassword = randompasswords.readlines()[choserandomnumber]

randomizedpassword = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in randomizedpassword]   #if you have fetched multiple lines while reading lines, it will remove \n from all values.

loginpsw = open('loginpsw.txt', 'w')
loginpsw.write(randomizedpassword)
loginpsw.close()
```

You can see few examples of what values are returned by `.readlines(size)` method. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is because `readlines()` adds a line break. You have the option of using `rstrip()` an example would be:

```py
with open('loginpsw.txt', 'w') as loginpsw: # automatically close file when done 
    loginpsw.write(randomizedpassword.rstrip('\n')) # strips last new line char
```

**Important security note**
The random library is **not**  cryptographically secure use the `secrets` library instead.

Comment: Also, `os.urandom()` returns crypto secure random bytes from the kernel

Comment: Yes but the docs recommend `secrets` [PEP 506](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506) because many coders use the old random functions improperly and this library is entirely designed for this. I would agree with you if OP needs python < 3.6